# Mac OS X - best place for the demo files of application?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to developing for the Mac OS X.

What's best place for storing the demo files of application on Mac OS X?

What's best  practices?

Comment: What do you mean by demo files?

Comment: These are examples of projects, that the user can use as a starting point to work with my application.

Comment: If you have demo files that the user shouldn't change, they I would suggest to put it inside the application's resource folder which then your application can make a copy of when the user opens the demo files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the "/Library/Application Support" directory, which the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH2-SW9) defines as: -

> *The Application Support directory is where your app stores any type of file that supports the app but is not required for the app to run, such as document templates or configuration files. The files should be app-specific but should never store user data.*

Comment: It looks good. Unfortunately by default, only the administrator has the write access to the /Library. That is the user is not able to save their data here.

Comment: Your question mentions demo files and you even commented that these are examples of projects, not files the user changes. In this case, the user should not be altering them. If the user wants to store files, it should be in their Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it.